# Rails - Export multiple models to CSV

Tags: ruby, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I am building a tool used for producing research reports. The tool produces reports with multiple models and nested models to display tabular data, and a report is structured something like this

```
Report
- main report attributes from report model

Nested Model 1
- nested model 1 attributes

Nested Model 2
- nested model 2 attributes
```

Right now I am exporting these reports to PDF, but I have gotten feature requests from users for exporting reports to Excel and CSV.

In my experience, CSV export has typically been good for "flat" associations, such as exporting a list of name/attributes from 1 model.

But if you have a complex report with multiple models, how do you structure an Excel / CSV file with data from multiple models?

Any examples of how you've structured something like this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the attributes of the nested model you want to list in the CSV file are all `has_one` relation, it is not complicated that you can just append the nested model attributes right to the main model, report.

```
attr1, attr2, attr3,...,attrN, nested_attr1, nested_attr2...
```

For `has_many` relation, it is the similar solution but a little bit more complicated. First, you need to find the maximum number of the nested models belongs to a report. For example, if a `report` has many `nested_reports`, you need to check each report and use `.count` to find the number of the `nested_reports` and then choose the biggest one. Once you found the max number X, you can make a CSV like this:

```
attr1,...,attrN, nested_report1_attr1...nested_report1_attrN, nested_report2_attr1...nested_report2_attrN,...nested_reportX_attr1...nested_reportX_attrN
```

If a report only has one nested_report, the nested_report2...nested_reportX can just be left blank.
If the report has multiple nested models, then just append them as the above.

If you have a large number of data, finding the max number of nested model of the report will be a bottleneck. You may need an elaborated JOIN SQL to optimize it. However, I personally choose another solution: use `counter_cache`, so I can find that number as fast as possible by using:

```rb
Report.all.maximum(:nested_model_count)
```

You can check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache about how to use `:counter_cache`